# Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed while trying to run 'php.exe composer.phar install'

Tags: composer-php

My english is not very good, so I want to say sorry now. I'll try my best.

I wanted to try Zend Framework2. I found this link http://framework.zend.com/downloads/skeleton-app and decided to try it. After that, I downloaded repository with example application https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication to C:\Sites\zf2\www. Guide says, that I need to open windows cmd and run some commands.

```
php.exe composer.phar self-update
php.exe composer.phar install
```

First opened ok and I checked for updates. But when I run install command I got this error:

```
10053 An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine can't download zend
```

I thought that windows firewall or KIS may block it, turn them off, but nothing happened. I still can't run this command.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Sorry for my bad english.

**add 1**: 
composer.phar passing all tests, so there are no problem with it

> C:\Sites\zf2\www>php.exe composer.phar diag

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking composer.json: Ok
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK
```

**add 2**: 
May be there are no problems with composer.phar and some programm blocks this connection?
I tried to connect directly to internet (I use router) - same error.
Also, I turned off KIS firewall and windows firewall - same result.

What can block it?

Comment: Your english is great. Do run `php.exe composer.phar diag` and post the result, please. This will try to access some known working resources and report on the success in more detail.

Comment: @Sven, oh! Are you kidding me? result: C:\Sites\zf2\www>php.exe composer.phar diag
Warning: This development build of composer is over 30 days old. It is recommend
ed to update it by running "composer.phar self-update" to get the latest version
.
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking http connectivity: OK
Checking composer.json: OK
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking composer version: OK p.s.: how i can go to next line? ENTER sends message

Comment: You can edit your question. The formatting is intentionally limited in the comments area.

Comment: Ok, i will add, that composer.phar passed check. Can you add something about my problem?

Comment: Not really. The error message you get seems to be some windows internal thing, which is not directly related to Composer.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain me what command 'php.exe composer.phar install' does? 
If I knew what this command is doing, I could have a more focused search. Thank you.

Comment: My pc is connected to internet via router. I tried to connect without router, directly. Same result.

Comment: Can you show your `composer.json` file? And do have `git` installed as command line version?

Comment: composer-json: {
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.2.*"
    },
 "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
. Yes, Git installed as command line version.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and after much frustration I nailed it down to a filtering software called "k9 web protection". It didn't help if I disabled the filter, I had to uninstall it.
I tried it on a few computers and the results were all the same. On 32 bit windows there was no issue but on 64 bit windows I had to uninstall k9, otherwise I continued getting this error.